# PHP is not executed on apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, php5

I run apache (Apache/2.2.14 Ubuntu). PHP is not executed. I noticed that the line

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm
```

was missing from /etc/apache2/apache.conf
I tried adding the line on several places in the .conf file. Nothing worked.

I tried `chown www-data /var/www/` and `chmod 777 /var/www` (i am new to linux)

I read that you might have to add

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

to httpd.conf. This also yields no result

I also tried executing this simple code (placed in /var/www/)

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

Firefox prompts me to save the file instead of executing it.

And yes, I did restart apache every time I made changes.

I am stuck.

edit:

`ls - l /var/` gives,

```
.....
.....
drwxrwxrwx  3 www-data www-data 4096 2011-12-05 14:39 www
```

Since apache runs in this group, the owner should be www-data, right?

the access log gives me:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Dec/2011:14:39:58 -0500] "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1" 200 327 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.18) Gecko/20110628 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.18"
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Dec/2011:14:45:35 -0500] "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1" 304 187 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.18) Gecko/20110628 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.18"
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Dec/2011:14:46:44 -0500] "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1" 304 187 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.18) Gecko/20110628 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.18"
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Dec/2011:14:53:26 -0500] "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1" 304 187 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.18) Gecko/20110628 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.18"
```

AND THE ERROR LOG:

```
[Mon Dec 05 14:25:08 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Dec 05 14:25:09 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 05 14:27:08 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Dec 05 14:27:09 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 05 14:35:33 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Dec 05 14:35:34 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 05 14:35:52 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Dec 05 14:35:53 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 05 14:45:29 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Dec 05 14:45:30 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 05 14:46:38 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Dec 05 14:46:39 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 05 14:54:16 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Dec 05 14:54:17 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: What do you get in apache access logs when you access the page?

Comment: @sachin see my edit please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you actually install PHP? Package `libapache2-mod-php5`? Normally, you should't need to edit any config files to activate PHP when installing this package.

Comment: I guess i did:

root@ubuntu:/var/log/apache2# php -v 
PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.10 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Oct 15 2011 00:09:58)

Comment: `php5-cli` is installed, but that doesn't mean the Apache module from `libapache2-mod-php5` is also installed. Please enter the command `aptitude show libapache2-mod-php5` and see if the `state` is `installed`.

Comment: was not installed indeed, installed the package, it works! thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Check the error log of apache. Check if you have the `LoadModule  php5_module modules/libphp5.so` or similar in apache configuration. Check that the libphp5.so file exist. Check that libphp5.so is loaded by apache with `pmap <apache_worker_PID>|grep php`. E.g. run:

```
ps -edf |grep apache|grep -v root|head -1|awk '{print $2}'|xargs pmap|grep php
```

You can enable php in apache on Ubuntu with:

```
sudo a2enmod php5
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 force-reload
```

See also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Installing_PHP_5

Comment: running this in the terminal gives me:
root@ubuntu:/var/log/apache2# pmap <apache_worker_PID>|grep php
bash: apache_worker_PID: No such file or directory
I tried replaicing apche_worker_PID with the path to apache2 ? i didnt understand pmap program.

Comment: you have to find a PID (process ID) of an apache worker using `ps`. E.g. `ps -edf|grep apache|grep -v root`

Comment: `<apache_worker_PID>` is a placeholder for the number that is the process identificator of apache worker. To see the processes, PIDs and other information you can use the `ps` command. `pmap` shows the how the memory was allocated for a process and will show all dynamic libraries loaded (both those loaded at startup and those loaded during the life of the process).

Comment: Thanks alot, the libapache package was not installed. that fixed it. it all boiled down to the same solution i guess, but thanks for the thorough explaination